# Image Cropper is not working properly - why?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-manifest

I am trying to build a what's app application but when I try to implement android image cropper in `build.gradle` it gave me some error like this

> "ERROR: Failed to parse XML in
>   H:\Project\WhatsApp2\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[17,9] Message: expected start or end tag Affected Modules:
>   app "

My code is given below

Android Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.whatsapp2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        <activity android:name=".PhoneLoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".GroupChatActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.whatsapp2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
}
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

For those, who still get an error even after adding dependency:

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
```

If your error may be something like:
**Classes of CropImage Library** were not auto suggested by IDE, then you must ensure this `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` and `jcenter()` in your project level build.gradle file.

Like this:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

It must work in that scenario. Hope! it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Temporary solution you can downgrade version as below:

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
```

Note : This error is regarding android jetpacks that may be updated in library.

Comment: I downgrade version of image cropper library but the error is same "ERROR: Failed to parse XML in H:\Project\WhatsApp2\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[17,9]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app
"

Comment: Post that `AndroidManifest.xml` in question.

Comment: I posted AndroidManifest.xml in my question

Comment: Remove this line from manifest file `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` You had wrote outside of `<application>` tag

Comment: Welcome, You can upvote and accept answer when you get enough reputation. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Recently this problem become very common when using android support library and third party libraries. Try migrating to androidX, it's pretty safe. And add:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in your `gradle.properties` which will automatically done if you migrate to androidX with android studio 3.2 plugin, to do this, go to refactor menu and choose migrate to androidX.

Comment: Where can i add "android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true " these lines?

Comment: in your gradle.properties, but you can't do it before migrating to androidX

Answer (score 0):

First convert your project into androidx by refactoring

```
Refactor-> Migrate to AndroidX -> Migrate
```

or add below lines in `gradle.properties` and manually change all widgets into androidx

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

And change this

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
```

into

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a **">"** *closing tag,* do it like :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">

    <activity android:name=".PhoneLoginActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".GroupChatActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />

</application>
```

Update : As you see there is an error in you `AndroidManifest.xml` file stating :

> expected start or end tag Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 0):

If you using below version of library

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
```

Then please add this line to your Proguard config file(`proguard-rules.pro`) and check it once

```
-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.** { *; }
```

and also remove `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` from manifest file 
which is outside of `<application>` tag